# creating query with subquery in yii

Tags: yii

Hi All I have following query to be executed. I am executing it as a string sql but is there any way I can convert it into criteria format or proper command format in Yii...

```
$sql="select * from costing inner join 
                (select * from storage inner join costing_user_binding psb on user.user=psb.fk_user_id where user.fk_users_id IN $parents_id)
                view on costing.costing_id=view.fk_costing_id where costing.fk_user_types_id = {$session['role_level']} and costing.fk_product_types_id=2";
            $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this...

`$subQuery=$model->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($model->getTableSchema(),$criteria)->getText();`

```
$mainCriteria=new CDbCriteria();
$mainCriteria->condition=' (col1,col2,col3) in ('.$subQuery.') ';
$mainCriteria->order = 'col1,col2,col3';
```

Comment: hey subquery is normal sql?

Comment: oops... sorry.. its oops.. sorry.. its $subQuery=$model->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($model->getTableSchema(),$criteria)->getText();